# Reducing the possibles roots for polynomials?

Tags: polynomials

I have a polynomial which $a_0$ is over $9000$, and finding all factors using the rational root theorem is beginning to be *very* long. I was thinking of factoring the whole polynomial using Ruffini's but I'm unsure how to actually proceed. Is there a method to reduce the number of possible factors?

Comment: What's the degree of the polynomial?

Comment: @PatrickStevens 5th, but I'm interested in a general form, since is very likely I will have some in a written test.

Comment: Does $a_0$ have an easy prime factorisation? There is no general form for the quintic or higher-degree polynomials.

Comment: @PatrickStevens the exact number is 8400, so, no. And yes, I know there isn't general form for 5th, but when I said "general form" I meant that the way to reduce possibles roots isn't dependent of the grade. What I'm looking for is to reduce possible $r/s$ permutations.

Comment: There are no shortcuts. Either use a computer, or your intuition.